# how do we configure the parameter inside lib from app layer

Tags: c

I have very basic question on C language.

#### Situation

- There is a library named "lib".
  The library has a member of array named "tmp".

> ```
> int tmp[ARRAY_SIZE];
> ```

currently ARRAY_SIZE is defined inside lib.

- Even though it is treated as library, we compile the library and app at the same time.(we are in non-OS environment)
- We can use static memory allocation only (no dynamic allocation)
  because of embedded system environment (where using heap is likely to be avoided)
- Since this is the library, we would like to be independent from application layer as much as possible

#### Goal

We would like to make ARRAY_SIZE configurable from app layer.

#### Question

In this situation, how do you modify this library to achieve the goal ?
Here is my ideas.

1. define "tmp" at application layer,
   then pass it as a pointer to the library at initialization time.
2. define the MACRO at compile time, like -DARRAY_SIZE=10
3. create header file like lib_setting.h at app layer, the include it from lib.h

Any other ideas ?
If you were me, how do you implement ?

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any other ideas ?

No, these are exactly the solutions to such problems.

> If you were me, how do you implement ?

It strongly depends on what the library is for and what exactly `ARRAY_SIZE` represent. For **sure** I would **not** call it `ARRAY_SIZE`, as the name [ARRAY_SIZE()](https://kernelnewbies.org/MagicMacros) is used in linux kernel I'm familiar with, so I would definitely pick a LIB_unique LIB_name LIB_with LIB_prefix.

If it's a library meant for normal regular use, I would definitely go with option 1 whenever possible.

```
struct lib_s {
   char *buf;
   size_t bufsize;
};
static int lib_init(struct lib_s *t, char *buf, size_t bufsize) {
    assert(t);
    assert(buf);
    assert(bufsize);
    t->buf = buf;
    t->bufsize = bufsize;
    return 0;
}
int lib_dosomething(struct lib_s *t);

// client
int main() {
   char mysuperbuffer[2046];
   struct lib_s lib;
   lib_init(&lib, mysuperbuffer, sizeof(mysuperbuffer));
}
```

Such design is easy to unit test. Is re-entrant. The lifetime is manageable. It's not spaghetti code. It's easy to understand and track variables. If user changes his mind, the user can choose if he wants to malloc or not. It's easy to refactor and extend later. Such design is found in many functions - `fopenbuf()` comes to my head from POSIX.

If it's a highly specialized library that profiling shows it's the bootleneck and the library needs super speed of execution and you don't want to waste `sizeof(char*) + sizeof(size_t)` bytes of memory and a lot more for indirection, I would go with option 3. Many projects use it - autotools generates a main `config.h` file, [mbedtls.h](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/include/mbedtls/config.h) has `mbedtls/config.h` file, etc.

If the configuration option is very constant and rarely changes, for example changes only when switching platforms, on windows it's something on linux it's something else, then maybe I would consider option 2, but I believe I would prefer to go option 3 anyway. Using a file is easier to track in control version systems and build systems will recompile only files that depend on a header that sees that definition. A macro passed on command line is harder to track which files use it (ie. spaghetti code) and usually when you change it's value, you have to recompile the whole project.

Comment: Great Thanks, KamilCuk for great explanation for each idea !!
Really appreciated !!